# Lock service does not work in Google Sheets using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am taking student attendance from an android app and it is storing in Google Sheets. It includes timestamp but for the analytics I need date only. So I used ON CHANGE trigger for timestamp. When a student enter his attendance (as below), the timestamp changes to date and a subject code is added to this (lastrow, 6) cell using ON CHANGE Trigger. But now the problem is, out of 50 rows of data 8-10 rows are not changing the timestamp to date so as the insertion of subject code is also missing in the corresponding row. Then I used Lock Service to limit concurrent access to users using try and catch method but it does not work. The dataset sample and apps script code are as follows:

The data are as below:

```
Timestamp  Student ID-Name Umail        Geoloc-Latitude   Geoloc-Longitude Subject-Code 
2020-03-24 1902032 1902032@bubt.ac.bd   23.8669328        90.2858456       ICTE4113
```

```js
function setSheetName(e) {
  try{
    var ss=e.source;
    var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var key=sh.getName();
    var lastRow=sh.getLastRow();
    var lastColumn=sh.getLastColumn();
    if((lastRow>1) && (key.indexOf("0")>-1 || key.indexOf("1")>-1 || key.indexOf("2")>-1 || key.indexOf("3")>-1 || key.indexOf("4")>-1 || key.indexOf("5")>-1 || key.indexOf("6")>-1 || key.indexOf("7")>-1 || key.indexOf("8")>-1 || key.indexOf("9")>-1)){
      sh.getRange(lastRow,6).setValue(key);     
      sh.getRange(lastRow,1).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    }       
    LockService.getScriptLock().waitLock(2000);//Throws exception if fail
    
  }catch(e){  
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    LockService.getScriptLock().releaseLock();
  }
  
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRyDF.jpg)

Comment: The lock needs to be obtained at the top of the function.  Put the `waitLock()` just underneath `try{`.

Comment: Sorry, I did that but the result remains the same. Wait Lock is not working!!

Comment: Is an error being caught?  `}catch(e){ Logger.log("Error: " + e.message);Logger.log("Stack: " + e.stack)`  Also, after running the code, click the View menu, and Execution Transcript or Executions.

Comment: No error was caught. However, there are some issues I guess in the Execution transcript. Please check the image attached just below the original post.

Comment: If an execution failed, there would be the word "Failed" in red in the status column, and I don't see that.

Comment: I think the problem is more logical than Lock Service. If two entries are done at the same time, trigger does not work for the first one but in case of second one (last row at that particular moment), trigger works fine. All my Col1 entries are the current date and all Col6 are the same sheet name where sheet name is the subject code(e.g. ICT4113). Is it possible to solve without locking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are setting the lock at the end of your `try` statement and releasing it inside the `catch`

This cannot work given that the [try..catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) blocks are not executed simultaneously - it is either the one or the other.

So either you have to wrap both parts of the statement withing the lock, or you use the lock only inside the `try` (because the `catch` will only be executed in case of failure).

Sample 1:

```js
function setSheetName(e) {
  LockService.getScriptLock().waitLock(2000);
  try{
    var ss=e.source;
    var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var key=sh.getName();
    var lastRow=sh.getLastRow();
    var lastColumn=sh.getLastColumn();
    if((lastRow>1) && (key.indexOf("0")>-1 || key.indexOf("1")>-1 || key.indexOf("2")>-1 || key.indexOf("3")>-1 || key.indexOf("4")>-1 || key.indexOf("5")>-1 || key.indexOf("6")>-1 || key.indexOf("7")>-1 || key.indexOf("8")>-1 || key.indexOf("9")>-1)){
      sh.getRange(lastRow,6).setValue(key);     
      sh.getRange(lastRow,1).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    }           
  }catch(e){  
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();    
  }
 LockService.getScriptLock().releaseLock(); 
}
```

Sample 2:

```js
function setSheetName(e) {
  try{
    LockService.getScriptLock().waitLock(2000);
    var ss=e.source;
    var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var key=sh.getName();
    var lastRow=sh.getLastRow();
    var lastColumn=sh.getLastColumn();
    if((lastRow>1) && (key.indexOf("0")>-1 || key.indexOf("1")>-1 || key.indexOf("2")>-1 || key.indexOf("3")>-1 || key.indexOf("4")>-1 || key.indexOf("5")>-1 || key.indexOf("6")>-1 || key.indexOf("7")>-1 || key.indexOf("8")>-1 || key.indexOf("9")>-1)){
      sh.getRange(lastRow,6).setValue(key);     
      sh.getRange(lastRow,1).setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    }
    LockService.getScriptLock().releaseLock();            
  }catch(e){  
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();    
  }
}
```